# Internal constant current driver for LED short circuits and blows when connected to AC main (120 V) without DC load

Tags: power-supply, led-driver, short-circuit, constant-current

I have AC 85-265V to 0.3A 8-12W DC 22-40V **Internal** constant current power supply for LED spot lights. This is the exact model https://www.lightinthebox.com/en/p/0-3a-8-12w-dc-22-40v-to-ac-85-265v-internal-constant-current-power-supply-driver-for-led-spot-lights_p1875439.html?prm=1.18.104.0

When connected to the AC main (120 V) the driver short circuits by the AC connection  points, resulting in a large spark and destroyed driver.
However, this does not occur if the DC output is wired to a 32 V LED chip, and the driver works fine.

Are internal constant current drivers required to be connected to a load (e.g. LED COB) before the AC current is switched on?

If this is the case, how would I prevent the driver from short-circuiting in the event that the LED chip dies?

Comment: Wonder why they reduced the price to $2 . No instruction guide?

Comment: Given the number of corners cut in the design, I'd advise to just buy a better driver. The higher price costs less than you trying to work around the bugs, even if you pay yourself a minimum wage. Of course it could be a great learning experience, but then you'd probably want to reverse-engineer the design properly, and then make it robust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are internal constant current drivers required to be connected to a load (eg. LED COB) before the AC current is switched on?

In this case, apparently yes.

> If this is the case, how would I prevent the driver from short-circuiting in the event that the LED chip dies?

You would need to put some sort of voltage limiter in parallel with the LED. But if the LED dies, this limiter will have to dissipate the same power (actually, slightly more) as the LED itself.

It sounds like the design cuts too many corners in order to cut cost; they've eliminated any sort of proper voltage limit in the switchmode controller. If the load goes open-circuit, the voltage just keeps rising until something inside the driver fails.

Comment: Dave, I used a string of 5 watt zeners in parallel with a variable load (MOV testing). The zeners in series were set to clamp at a voltage just above a normal "high" load, so the feedback loop was not broken.